# ReferenceError: progress is not defined (tesseract)

Tags: javascript, tesseract, worker

I'm trying to upload a file that's being processed by tesseract, but when uploading nodemon gives me the follow error.

```
C:\Users\blah\Documents\Java Scripts\app.js:32
      worker.recognize(data, "eng", { tessjs_create_pdf: "1" }),
             ^

ReferenceError: progress is not defined
    at C:\Users\blah\Documents\Java Scripts\app.js:32:14
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
```

```
////Routes
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    fs.readFile(`./uploads/${req.file.originalname}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return console.log("Dit gaat niet werken bel xxx", err);

      worker
        .recognize(data, "eng", { tessjs_create_pdf: "1" })
        .progress((progress) => {
          console.log(progress);
        })
        .then((result) => {
          res.send(result.text);
        })
        .finally(() => worker.terminate());
    });
  });
});
```

In the beginning of the code the imports are defined as follows:

```
const { createWorker } = require("tesseract.js");
const worker = createWorker();
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used tesseract.js but based on their github aren't you missing steps before recognize?

```
import { createWorker } from 'tesseract.js';

const worker = createWorker({
  logger: m => console.log(m)
});

(async () => {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');
  const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed tesseract v2 and do the following steps.
Step 1- initialize tesseract worker and setup logger to monitor process
Step 2- Setup storage options to upload file inside upload directory
Step 3- Initialize upload with storage options
step 4 - set view engine
step 5- Handle all requests comes on /upload route

The following part shows how you should use tesseract recognize() method
step 6- use recognize method and print result to console
step 7- Generate pdf
step 8- send respond to view with result text
step 9- terminate tesseract

````
//////////////Step 2////////////////////////////
const {createWorker } = require('tesseract.js');


const worker = createWorker({
    logger: m => console.log(m)
});

//////////////Step 2////////////////////////////
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cd) => {
        cd(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

//////////////Step 3////////////////////////////
const upload = multer({ storage }).single('YOURFILENAME');

//////////////Step 4////////////////////////////
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

//////////////Step 5////////////////////////////

app.post('/upload', (req, res) =>{

    upload(req, res, err =>{  
        console.log(req)
        
        fs.readFile(`./uploads/${req.file.originalname}`, (err, data) => {

            // displaying error if any
            if(err) return console.error("this is error", err);


            (async()=>{
                await worker.load();
                await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
                await worker.initialize('eng');

                //////////////Step 6////////////////////////////
                const {data: {text}} = await worker.recognize(data);
                console.log(text);

                //////////////Step 7////////////////////////////
                const{data: pdfData} = await worker.getPDF('Teserract OCR Result');
                fs.writeFileSync(`${req.file.originalname}.pdf`, Buffer.from(pdfData));
                console.log(`Generaate PDF: ${req.file.originalname}.pdf`);

                //////////////Step 8//////////////////////////// 
                res.send(text)
//////////////Step 9////////////////////////////
                await worker.terminate();
            })();
        })

    })
})

```
````